# Is there any way to load odbc driver manually to my c# application?

Tags: c#, database, odbc, driver

The thing is that I am not taking about connection to the ODBC drivers that already installed on my computer with DSN, I am talking about loading the DLL of the odbc driver to the c# program and connect even if the driver is not installed on the computer.

Thanks a lot